# Usage of custom freemarker template

Tags: freemarker

I was wondering if anyone can help me with Apache FreeMarker? I'm trying to use a custom model but I can't figure it out.

Imagine I want to dump the result of a query (java ResultSet in a FreeMarker template). What is the best approach?

I have found on Google the class: ResultSetTemplateModel

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import freemarker.template.SimpleScalar;
import freemarker.template.TemplateHashModel;
import freemarker.template.TemplateModel;
import freemarker.template.TemplateModelException;
import freemarker.template.TemplateSequenceModel;


public class ResultSetTemplateModel implements TemplateSequenceModel {

    private ResultSet rs = null;
    public ResultSetTemplateModel(ResultSet rs) {
        this.rs = rs;
    }
    public TemplateModel get(int i) throws TemplateModelException {
        try {
            rs.next();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new TemplateModelException(e.toString());
        }
        TemplateModel model = new Row(rs);
        return model;
    }

    public int size() throws TemplateModelException {
        int size=0;
        try {
            rs.last();
            size = rs.getRow();
            rs.beforeFirst();
        } catch (Exception e ) {
            throw new TemplateModelException( e.toString());
        }
        return size;
    }


    class Row implements TemplateHashModel {

        private ResultSet rs = null;
        public Row(ResultSet rs) {
            this.rs = rs;
        }

        public TemplateModel get(String s) throws TemplateModelException {
            TemplateModel model = null;
            try {
                model = new SimpleScalar( rs.getString(s) );
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            return model;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() throws TemplateModelException {
            boolean isEmpty = false;
            if ( rs == null ) { isEmpty = true; }
            return isEmpty;
        }

    }
}
```

And I have a very simple class (I even made it easier than previous):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_27);
        cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
        cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(MyCLASS.class, "/");
        StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new TreeMap<>();

        ResultSet rs = getResultSet("Select foo, bar FROM my_table");
        parameters.put("hello", "World");
        parameters.put("result", rs);


        Template temp = cfg.getTemplate("template.txt");
        temp.process(parameters, out);

        System.out.println("out = " + out);
    } catch (IOException | TemplateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

My template

```
Hello ${hello}
<#-- how do I specify ResultSet columns here ?? -->
```

How can I use the custom template?? Any advice?? I know how to load the template file. But I don't know how to specify that it is a custom model in the template.

THank you guys for the support :)

Comment: I don't see any FreeMarker API-s used in `main`, nor any attempt to specify the data to display (the data-model, aka. template context). (While FreeMarker has a `TemplateLoader` class, it has no `loadQuery` method, so yours must come from somewhere else.)

Comment: Also, read https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_quickstart.html if you haven't yet. Again, because your example seems not to do anything like that.

Comment: Well, I didn't thought it could be of any interest. I know how to load the template file. That is definitely not the point here. Sorry...

My pont is... By default, freemarker can handle scalar types, List, etc. But, there is not support for ResultSet. So, I was looking on Google and I've found the ResultSetTemplateModel but I have no clue on how to use it :( . I've read the doc, but I didn't get it actuall :( 

Any help? Thank you anyway :)

Comment: OK, see my answer. BTW, you are talking about a "custom template", but there's no such thing (templates are always "custom", as FreeMarker doesn't come with any). It's a custom object wrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of using `ResultSetTemplateModel` for wrapping `ResultSet`-s:

- Either extend `DefaultObjectWrapper` by overriding `handleUnknownType`, where you return `new ResultSetTemplateModel((ResultSet) obj)` if `obj` is a `ResultSet`, otherwise call `super`. Then use `Configuration.setObjectWrapper` to actually use it.
- Or, add `new ResultSetTemplate(rs)` to `parameters` instead of `rs`; if something is already a `TempalteModel`, it will not be wrapped again. Note that if you get a `ResultSet` from somewhere else in the template, this approach will not work as it avoids your manual wrapping, so extending the `DefaultObjectWrapper` is what you want generally.

Note that the `ResultSetTemplateModel` implementation shown is quite limited. The `ObjectWrapper` should be passed to the constructor as well, and stored in a final field. Then, instead of `new SimpleScalar( rs.getString(s) )` it should do `objectWrapper.wrap(rs.getObject(s))`.

Comment: Nice!! It works like a charm!! Thank you very much. Now, I will try to see how I can create my own wrapper to dump the content of the ResultSet without even specifying each attribute.

Comment: Do you think that it will be possible to have a value like ${myResultSet} in the template and in the custolm Model, it loops throught the resultset and prints it?? 

Thank you again!!

Comment: I've found the answer. I just need to  implements TemplateScalarModel and return the getAsString(). 

Thank you :)